# Automate computing resubstitution error from printcp output result

Tags: r, performance, r-caret, rpart, confusion-matrix

I have an output for my printcp but I don't know how to call certain variables from it. For example:

```
data(iris)
library(caret)
idx <- createDataPartition(iris$Species,list=FALSE, p = .67,times = 1)
IrisTrain <- iris[ idx,]
IrisTest  <- iris[-idx,]

iris_model <- rpart(Species ~ ., data = IrisTrain)
err_mat<-printcp(iris_model)
err_mat
```

gives me an output that looks like this:
[image]

Now I know that I can calculate resubstitution error by computing:
 (.66667*.044118)*100 = 2.94%
But is there a way that I don't have to do this manually?

Also I can call upon 0.044118 by:

```
colnames(err_mat)
```

which outputs certain variables: "CP"        "nsplit"    "rel error" "xerror"    "xstd" 
and I can extract 0.044118 by:

```
lenn=length(err_mat[,'rel error'])
err_mat[lenn,'rel error']
```

**But how do I grab the Root Node Error????**

I am trying to run this multiple times and I **need to be able to call whatever the rootnodeerror is**. Then I can just compute with the variables.

**Otherwise if this is not possible what is the code to compute re substitution error?** I feel like I have looked everywhere and it's all manual from results and not actual automated code as I want to loop multiple times and need to call variables.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at `str(err_mat)` and `str(summary(err_mat))`. Root node error should be in there somewhere.

Comment: `sos::findFn("printcp")` suggests there are three packages on CRAN with that function. Which are you using, `rpart`, `itree`, or `mvpart`? the `rpart` function is in both `rpart` and `mvpart`.